# ASP.NET Response time of Login page

Tags: asp.net-2.0

net application, i have one intermediate page(index.aspx) between login.aspx and default1.aspx.

The job of index.aspx page is to check authenticated user role and then just redirect request to valid defaultpage i.e default1.aspx, default2.aspx, default3.aspx.

For this type of requirement our loginpage rendering time is more also after authentication default page rendring time is also high.

For login page it will take around 30-40 sec for first client request.

Please suggest me right way to solve this so that login page come as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this isn't just ASP.NET startup time, effectively? I suggest you create an unauthenticated page which just has static text, just for test purposes - I suspect that will take just as long as your login page.

If it's *not* startup time, I suggest you sprinkle your login page with logging so you can see exactly when it's got to which bit of code - that should help you track down the bottleneck. While you're waiting for the login page, is the CPU busy on the server?

Comment: Hi Jon, Actually i have used fiddler to monitor th response. It shows the response time of Login.aspx 30-40 sec and cssfile and javascript file will came winin a second. But those file starts after login.aspx response.

Comment: That's not showing you anything about what's going on inside the server though. If it's not just ASP.NET startup, you need to write server-side logs so you get more than "request received at X, response received at Y."

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use asp.net authentication membership class?

Judging by your question, it doesn't seem that you are.

Comment: actually i have 3 default page and 3 type of category for user, based upon login user category i need to redirect request to appropriate default page.
Therefore i take intermeediate page to redirect user at appropriate defaultpage.

If you have any other good solution . Please send me.